# How can I see translations for the specific language in rails console? Using I18n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I can see translations for the default language using the Rails console using this code:

```
I18n.t('views.signup.company_info')
```

But how can I see translations for the german language?

Answer (score 1):

For displaying the translation for the specific language we need to set the locale:

```
I18n.t('views.signup.company_info', locale: :de)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I18n.with_locale(:de) {I18n.t('views.signup.company_info')}
```

If you want to use a specific language for translation in a code block you can do this:

```
I18n.with_locale(locale) do
  your_code
end
```